# OFII stamp issue

Tags: customs-and-immigration, france, thailand, thai-citizens, ofii

I am a Thai citizen and I am currently living in France with a student long-stay visa (1 year). I am planning to go back to Thailand this December for two weeks however my concern is about my departure and arrival back to France (to continue my studies) since next December my arrival in France will be over 3 months in the past and I haven't got the stamp from OFII (Office Français de l'Immigration et de l'Intégration).

I did receive a receipt from OFII. It shows that these period of time the office is quite busy. My documents are in the process but it might not be on time to get the stamp before leaving France back to Thailand.

My question is will I be able to go back to France with my long stay visa + an OFII receipt (without the stamp)?

Comment: Is the visa expired?

Comment: Some friend did that and had no issue but is from a country whose citizens are not required a visa to enter in France as tourists (and the immigration officer did not flip through the passport).

Comment: @MichaelHampton The visa is not expired (the expiry date on the sticker is well into the future) but nonetheless not supposed to be valid after 3 months in France if you do not have the additional OFII stamp, that's the confusing thing (I know because it's a common problem). In practice, if you apply in time and remain in France, you won't get any problem if you go over the three-month threshold but I haven't been able to figure out the exact status of this mostly-but-not-quite-valid visa under Schengen rules.

Comment: See also http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/59099/leaving-france-without-having-gotten-ofii-stamp (not a duplicate but a related question).