# Can I leave France without an OFII stamp on a student visa?

Tags: visas, schengen, indian-citizens, france, ofii

I'm an Indian citizen and I'm currently studying in France. Unfortunately, my school is pretty bad and I'd like to terminate my studies and return back to India, If I leave France just over three months after my arrival, will I be refused exit from the country?

Will the French police not allow me to return to my country? I actually came to France on October 2nd but I think it's very hard for me to leave within three months of my arrival since air tickets during the holiday seasons are expensive. If I leave on the 5th or 6th of January, can the French border guards detain me for not having an OFII stamp and actually "deport" me instead of granting me exit?

Also, can my school tell the border agency of France to stop me from leaving the country or to start deportation proceedings against me?

They don't like me that much - that's the reason why I'm asking this question. I'm sorry if I sound naive, but I'm not very well aware of French laws and regulations.

Comment: This post might give you the answer: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/59099/leaving-france-without-having-gotten-ofii-stamp?rq=1

Comment: @frostshoxx Hi, thanks for replying back but please note that in that question, the person is a US citizen not an Indian citizen like me and is on a long stay visitor visa not on a student visa like me. I'd like to know if I can leave France.